# Undefined reference to `__cxa_thread_atexit@@CXXABI` when compiling with `libc++` on linux

Tags: c++, linux, linker, clang, libc++

I'm trying to compile my projects on **Arch Linux x64** using **libc++**, **libc++abi** and **clang++ 3.6.0**.

The projects compile properly, but fail to link with the following error:

> error: CMakeFiles/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_thread_atexit@@CXXABI_1.3.7'
>
> /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

I'm compiling and linking using the `-stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi` flags.

Is there any additional library I should link? Am I missing a flag?

Comment: A quick Google search suggests that this is not implemented in the C++ ABI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either link with `-lsupc++` or provide a small wrapper function
(probably the better way for `libc++`) for the glibc implementation:

```
extern "C" int __cxa_thread_atexit(void (*func)(), void *obj,
                                   void *dso_symbol) {
  int __cxa_thread_atexit_impl(void (*)(), void *, void *);
  return __cxa_thread_atexit_impl(func, obj, dso_symbol);
}
```

It may be worth to mention that this only works with glibc >= 2.18.