# Error libc++.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetRegionStart'

Tags: c++, ld, clang++

I'm trying to have my first embryo of C++ compiled with `clang++-4.0`

my code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>

// this line is to deal with the link error:
// "undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_thread_atexit@@CXXABI..."
// cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29322666/356440
extern "C" int __cxa_thread_atexit(void (*func)(), void *obj,
                                   void *dso_symbol) {
  int __cxa_thread_atexit_impl(void (*)(), void *, void *);
  return __cxa_thread_atexit_impl(func, obj, dso_symbol);
}

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile with `clang++-4.0`, and link with `ld` this way:

```
clang++-4.0 -c main.cpp -o main.o
ld -o test main.o -lc++ -lc++abi -lc
```

It's as if I'm missing to link with another library, but I don't know which one or ones.

Do you see what's wrong or missing ? I think I'm missing some beginner stuff for doing c++ stuffs with `clang++` on linux.

Compilation errors:

> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to
>   0000000000400380 main.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init':
>   main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to`
>   std::ios_base::Init::Init()' main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x19): undefined
>   reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
>   main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2d): undefined reference to`__dso_handle'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so: undefined reference to
>   `_Unwind_GetRegionStart' //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so:
>   undefined reference to`_Unwind_RaiseException'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so: undefined reference to
>   `_Unwind_SetIP' //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so: undefined
>   reference to`_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so: undefined reference to
>   `_Unwind_Resume' //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so: undefined
>   reference to`_Unwind_GetIP' //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so:
>   undefined reference to `_Unwind_SetGR'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so: undefined reference to`
>   _Unwind_DeleteException'

Comment: Possible dublicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think it's a dupplicate. Here the undefined reference is not linked to my code. Here I try to compile a main function that simply returns 0... nothing else...

Comment: That's why I didn't dupe hammer your question.

Comment: What happens when you add `-lcpp` _at the end_ of the command line? Is this a version of `clang` installed via a package manager, or did you build it from source?

Comment: installed via package manager, with apt.llvm.org added to my apt sourcelist. When I add at linking `-lcpp`, `ld` complains it doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not link C++ applications with `ld`. Link with the C++ compiler executable because it links in all the necessary libraries:

```
clang++-4.0 -c main.cpp -o main.o
clang++-4.0 -o test main.o
```